# Send a random number from one function to be used by another.

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, return

I am working on a word game with javascript.

I need to pass a random number created by an onclick event in one function to another. The other function fires with a onclick event.

(I allready tried to send the random number as a parameter to the new
funcion and it worked, but not with the clickevent)

The first method, spelet.word, picks a random eng word fron an array of 10 words.

The second method, spelet.answer, checks if it is correctly spelled. It does so by taking the same randomly generated number from first method to pick the right word for the array of words.

Problem is I cant acess the randomly created number from the first method with onclick.

The relevant HTML

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="eng" id="eng" />
  <!-- the english word-->
  <input type="text" value="sve" id="sve" />
  <!-- the swedish word-->

  <input type="button" value="Nytt Ord" onclick='spelet.word();' />
  <br />
  <!-- Generates a random english word from an array of 10 words-->
  <input type="button" value="Svara" onclick='spelet.answer();' />
  <br />
  <!-- The user use this button to submit the swedish word-->
</form>
```

```js
var $Lars = {};
var objwords = //Måste ha som global för att alla metoder ska nå den.
  {
    ord: [{
      eng: "bird",
      sve: "fågel"
    }, {
      eng: "car",
      sve: "bil"
    }, {
      eng: "food",
      sve: "mat"
    }, {
      eng: "coffee",
      sve: "kaffe"
    }, {
      eng: "water",
      sve: "vatten"
    }, {
      eng: "woman",
      sve: "kvinna"
    }, {
      eng: "cup",
      sve: "kopp"
    }, {
      eng: "pen",
      sve: "penna"
    }, {
      eng: "beer",
      sve: "öl"
    }, {
      eng: "desert",
      sve: "öken"
    }, {
      eng: "stone",
      sve: "sten"
    }]
  }


$Lars.Play = function() 
  {
    var c;
    this.word = function() {
      //---------- doing a random number-----------------// 
      var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      //spelet.answer(c); DID NOT WORK
      document.getElementById('eng').value = objwords.ord[c].eng;
      var i = 0; //using the random number to pick up en english word
      for (i = 0; i < objwords.ord.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('eng').value = objwords.ord[c].eng;
      }
      document.getElementById('nr').value = c;
      //return c; DID NOT WORK
    }

    this.answer = function() //the same random number picks up the swedish word and
      //check if it is correct spelled
      {
        var svaret = document.getElementById('sve').value;
        var q = 0;
        for (q = 0; q < objwords.ord.length; q++) {
          if (objwords.ord[c].sve == svaret) {} //something happens when correct answer;}
          else {} //something happens when incorrect answer;}
        }
      }
  }
var spelet = new $Lars.Play();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a more globaly scoped variable for that. A minimal example:

```
function Play (){
  this.c = -1;
}

Play.prototype.word = function(){
  this.c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  console.log("Produced: " + this.c);
}
Play.prototype.answer = function(){
  console.log("Got " + this.c);
}

var playit = new Play();
playit.word();
playit.answer();
playit.word();
playit.answer();
```

You don't need to spell the protoypes out, I just thought it would make it more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your sulotion mate. I am a retarded man on javaScripting so it will take some hours for me on tweaking but this looks as an answer. I post when I am finished. Thanks again.